# How to call anonymous functions in swift

Tags: swift, flutter

I am not an expert in iOS or swift. I want to call two anonymous functions of a class. They are like listeners. Below is my code:

```
let streamChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: "com.sagar.no_plugins/channelDemo", binaryMessenger: controller)
    streamChannel.setStreamHandler({
        //onCancel(args: Any?)->FlutterError
       //onListen(args: Any?, sink: EventSink?) -> FlutterError
    })
```

How can I call these two methods which I have commented?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: There is no code sample or documentation for this. There is only the class name and available methods in the doc.

Comment: Well, what doc?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/EventChannel.html @Alexander

Comment: That's a Java API, does Flutter somehow make it available to Swift?

Comment: This is an example from official git repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/platform_channel_swift/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: I don’t want to implement the way they have done by implementing FlutterEventHandler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195366/discussion-between-alexander-and-sagar-suri).